# Python 2.7 TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7

After looking through all the other questions of this nature the answer seems to be the same, that the coder is not passing the arguments because they've left `__init__()` blank. However, in the code below I have not left it blank and have tried to pass all four arguments as seen in the last line.

Yet I'm still getting the `TypeError`. I can't figure out why the arguments I am trying to pass are being ignored.

```
class Login:
    def __init__(self, username, password, site):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.site = "http://" + site + ".wikia.com"
        Login.login(self)

    def login(self):
        self.session = requests.session()
        login_data = {'action': 'login', 'lgname': self.username, 'lgpassword': self.password, 'format':'json'}
        response = self.session.post(self.site + "/api.php",data=login_data)
        content = json.loads(response.content)
        login_data['lgtoken'] = content['login']['token']
        response = self.session.post(self.site + "/api.php",data=login_data)
        content = json.loads(response.content)
        if content['login']['result'] != 'Success':
            raise Exception("Login error: Could not log in via MediaWiki API.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Login = Login()
    Login.__init__(self, "username", "password", "site")
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `__init__` is called when you call a constructor....so it never *gets* to your second line. Aside from that, you're not passing a valid instance to your `__init__` call. What do you think `self` is supposed to be?

Comment: May I suggest that you stop whatever you are working on, and run through the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). It is better to learn it right the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `__init__` incorrectly, use this instead. `__init__` is called when you are initialising the new object automatically:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    login = Login("username", "password", "site")
```

You should check [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) about the same as well.

Answer (score 8):

While mu 無 [shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29581174/1426065) the correct way to do it, I wanted to emphasize something in his code that fixes another issue in yours. Your code is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Login = Login()
    Login.__init__(self, "username", "password", "site")
```

Even if you instantiated `Login()` correctly by running

```
Login = Login("username", "password", "site")
```

you wouldn't be able to use your `Login` class again, because you just overwrote it with your `Login` variable. Make sure your instance is not the same as the class name, use

```
login = Login("username", "password", "site")
```

instead.